# Search Tweets with Twitter Search API V1.1 in c#

Tags: c#, twitter, console-application

I have an application that uses the twitter search API V1.

The main target of this application is to get tweets from a specific topic. With the twitter API V1 I just use this URL to search: http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=Topic&rpp=100&page=1

But now there is an update of the twitter API to V1.1.

I was searching how it works and you need to add some authentication tokens and keys when you make connection with the twitter API (Consumer key, Consumer secret, Access token & Access token secret).

I have really no idea how to add these keys/tokens to my URL or how to make connection with the new twitter API.

If someone has any experience in getting tweets in C# (console application) with the new API I would like to know more about it.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but I have created a GitHub project that calls the twitter api and has a console project included.

It is available here:

https://github.com/andyhutch77/oAuthTwitterTimeline

I had to generate an oAuth consumer key and secret from Twitter at:

https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new